# intellij play framework 2.0.2 configuration

Tags: playframework, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

Any idea how to configure Intellij Idea to use the 2.0.2 play framework in the play console?

I've updated my application to 2.0.2 (outside of Intellij) but can not  run it inside Intellij because the console always starts up as **2.0.1**.

Comment: You should wait a couple of days. Play 2.0.2 is now two days old.

Comment: See also http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-82967.

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this issue a couple of days ago and created a blog post about it after I found how it can be solved for the time being: http://wordpress.rintcius.nl/post/update-play-framework-configuration-in-intellij

To summarise (IntelliJ 11.1.2 on Linux):

1. Close IntelliJ
2. Open file ~/.IntelliJIdea11/config/options/other.xml
3. Change the home value in this entry: 
   `<component name="PlayframeworkConfiguration" home="$USER_HOME$/programs/play-2.0.1" />`

Comment: That config key is nowhere to be found in 11.1.3!

Comment: @jeshan I am now also on 11.1.3 and in my case it's still there (although with a different home value since I have upgraded in the meantime). Are you on Linux as well? Do you have a working Play integration or are you starting from scratch?